# Convert a picklist fieldtype to a number fieldtype without losing data

Tags: custom-field

So we have a large number of text fields that we want to convert to number fields without losing data. We have a script to write to convert the text to numbers, so for example it was

- Monthly
- Weekly
- Yearly

so we converted Monthly to 12, weekly to 52 and yearly to 1, so far so good.

But when we take that and convert the field to a number field it just whips out the data

is there anyway way to make sure it saves the data when you convert the fieldtype?

Comment: I assume 'whips out' means 'wipes out' ?

Answer (score 1):

It whips out the data because even though you are "converting" your values to "numbers", they are still stored as a text datatype in that text type field. When you convert the field over, it will have an incompatible data type inside of it and will clear it out.

I don't really know the details of the scenario, but i would just export that field out with the record ID, change the field type, and then reinsert those values in as Numbers.

Comment: Sorry. I guess i need to back up my statement too since I'm still n00b

**Changing to Number from any other type**

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm